# Python error in installing package 'hpelm' via pip on windows

Tags: python, pip, hdf5

I am trying to install [hpelm](https://pypi.org/project/hpelm/) on my machine via `pip install hpelm` but getting this error - [image of the error thrown in commandline while installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfctP.png). I tried lots of things to solve it like:

1.Installing anaconda

2.Uninstalling anaconda and installing python 3.7 (64-bit) from python.org and then installing numpy+mkl, scipy, scikitlearn from the windows binary hosted by Christoph Gohlke ([link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)).

3.Installing numpy, scipy, scikit-learn via `pip install 'package_name'`

None of the above methods worked. I'm using Windows-10 (64-bit), Python 3.7.1 (64-bit). I have wasted hours on it. Is there something basic that I might be missing? I'm kinda new to this. Please help me install this package.

Comment: Right above the red message it tells you why it fails; you apparently don't have HDF5 installed or configured correctly.

Comment: @BilalAliJafri why? The error is pretty explicit about why it fails

Comment: This is a problem with Python3.7, as seen in this Github [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3884). It works fine if you try on Python 3.6. I've installed it without issues on Python3.6.7.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: @roganjosh I installed h5py explicitly via `pip install h5py`, but still getting the same error while installing hpelm. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @RoadRunner Thanks a lot! That solved this nightmare. I finally reverted to python 3.6.7 and it finally installed and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a problem with Python3.7, as seen in this Github [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3884). It works fine if you try on Python 3.6. I installed it fine on Python3.6.7.